# What is this strange inheritance loop?

Tags: java, debugging, inheritance

I have created a basic inheritance program using a polymorphic array. From the parent-class, this array is looped through and each object (created from the child-class) at each index executes the parent-class' instance method.

     As an experiment, I created an object within the child-class' constructor of its' parent-class type, and executed the parent-class' instance method from there.

     For reasons unknown to me, this is causing the instance method (executed from the child-class' constructor) *to execute the number of times as the length of the parent-class' polymorphic array* (if the polymorphic array has **5** elements, the child-class' method call will be executed **5** times).

---

Here is the parent-class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // instance variables
    protected String name;
    protected String numStrings;

    // constructor
    public MyClass(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // instance method
    public void getDescription()
    {
        System.out.println("The " + name + " has " + numStrings + " strings.");
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass[] instruments = new MyClass[2];

        instruments[0] = new Child("Ibanez bass guitar");
        instruments[1] = new Child("Warwick fretless bass guitar");

        for(int i = 0, len = instruments.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            instruments[i].getDescription();
        }
    } // end of main method
} // end of class MyClass
```

...here is the child-class:

```
public class Child extends MyClass
{
    // constructor
    public Child(String name)
    {
        super(name); // calling the parent-class' constructor
        super.numStrings = "four";

        MyClass obj = new MyClass("asdf");
        obj.getDescription();
    }
} // end of class Child
```

...and here is the output:

```
The asdf has null strings.
The asdf has null strings.
The Ibanez bass guitar has four strings.
The Warwick fretless bass guitar has four strings.
```

Comment: There is no inheritance loop here. `MyClass obj` appears to be more confusing than useful so I would remove it.

Comment: Remember that output streams (System.out, System.err) are not synchronized, so the order of outputs is accidental.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinSanecki, this is interesting... So are they executed in the order of processing time then? And what might be a better alternative for testing?

Comment: nevermind... you don't use different streams, only System.out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic line is this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass("asdf");
```

if you just simply call getDescription() instead of obj.getDescription(), it should be OK. Since 'Child' extends 'MyClass' the super constructor call is for initializing everything in the super class (let's just say you can imagine it for now as an implicit `new MyClass("...")`) you don't have to instantiate 'MyClass' explicitly.

Comment: +1 This is the same as not creating the `new MyClass` at all which doesn't appear to be needed.

Comment: Ok, nvmnd I understand that part now, as explained by `tucuxi` here.

Answer (score 3):

No strange inheritance loop anywhere. You create two Child instances, each of which executes this code

```
    MyClass obj = new MyClass("asdf");
    obj.getDescription();
```

And prints "The asdf has null strings.", as expected. Note that `obj` is ready for garbage-collection, as it is no longer accessible after this code executes. That is, these two lines are unnecessary and their only effect is to output "The asdf has null strings". The superclass's constructor is already called when you write super("something").

And then, the two Child objects are finally printed, with correct values.

Comment: Thanks @tucuxi! Ah, I see -- so the first line here prints the message, and then the second line here prints the message as well (in congruence with the length of the array being looped through in the main method). Could you please explain further about the superclass's constructor being "...generated implicitly even if you did not include it yourself"?

Comment: Oops, my bad - constructors are only implicitly called if they have no parameters. Fixed my answer.